# DataTables: convert NaN to something else

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, datatables

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Johnny', 'Michelle'},
                   'quiz': [10, np.nan],
                   'test': [np.nan, 49]})
```

I'm passing this data to a DataTables table. How can I convert `NaN` to something more readable? I've tried using the `defaultContent` option but that appears to be only for data that's completely missing. Also my actual table has many columns. If there's an easier way to apply this change to the entire table (all columns) instead of explicitly defining it for each column, that would be helpful as well (http://jsfiddle.net/ndaboky3/3/).

```
$('.display').DataTable({
  data: data,
  columns: [
    {data: 'name'},
    {data: 'quiz',
     defaultContent: 'No Data'
    },
    {data: 'test',
     defaultContent: 'No Data'
    }]
})
```

Comment: Does it really say `np.nan`, or does it say `NaN`? You could just search and replace in the array before passing it to dataTables, but you'd have to know what to search for

Comment: @adeneo It says NaN. I wrote `np.nan` above to make it easy to copy/paste for testing purposes

Comment: `df.replace(np.nan, ' - ')`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I need to perform calculations on the DataFrame so I'd rather keep it intact and handle this client-side

Answer (score 0):

You could create a recursive function that replaces object values at all depths, something like

```
(function rec(d) {
  $.each(d, function(k, v) {
    if (typeof v === 'object') return rec(v)
    if (isNaN(v) && typeof v === 'number') d[k] = 'No Data';
  })
})(data);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ndaboky3/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You could change all the NaN in the pandas DataFrame with `fillna`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Johnny', 'Michelle'],
    'quiz': [10, np.nan],
    'test': [np.nan, 49]
})

filled = df.fillna('no data')
```

You then get:

```
print(filled)
       name     quiz     test
0    Johnny       10  no data
1  Michelle  no data       49
```

A caveat will be that it messes with your dtypes, I'm not sure if that will matter in your context.